# Orientation of a vector space from a homological point of view

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-spaces, orientation

I was reading Milnor and Stasheff's *Characteristic Classes* but I got stuck at the beginning of Chapter 9 when a homological interpretation of the orientation of a real vector space is given. More precisely, an orientation of an $n$-dimensional real vector space $V$ can also be viewed as a choice of generator of the infinite cyclic group $H_n(V,V-\{0\})$.

It follows from the text that the claim behind this fact is the following:

> Let $V$ be a real vector space of dimension $n$ and $\phi: V \to V$ be a linear isomorphism. Then the induced map
> $$\phi_*: H_n(V,V-\{0\}) \longrightarrow H_n(V,V-\{0\})$$
> is
> $$\phi_*=
> \begin{cases}
> \text{id} \quad & \text{if} \ \det \phi > 0 \\
> -\text{id} \quad & \text{if} \ \det \phi < 0 \\
> \end{cases} \quad .$$

Of course, $\phi_*$ can only be $\pm \text{id}$ because it is a group automorphism of the infinite cyclic group.

Could someone help me to prove this statement? Any help is very welcome.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Automorphisms take generators to generators.   There's $2$ options:   $1\mapsto \pm1$.

Comment: @Noobie Yes, this is mentioned in the first comment after the statement. The question is to determine when it is +1 and when -1, depending on the orientation-preserving properties of $\phi$.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ has exactly two path components. One for positive $det$ and one for negative. And so it is enough to consider two linear automorphisms: the identity and the reflection. Does this help?

Comment: @freakish That's a good remark, indeed. However, I was thinking there should be a simpler/more direct proof of this fact.

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality, we may assume $V = \mathbb{R}^n$. Note that any invertible matrix $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ can be written as a finite product of elementary matrices. It follows that $\phi$ is a composition of linear maps representing these elementary matrices. It suffices to show that if $E$ is the elementary matrix of interchanging two rows, then the corresponding linear map induces $-\text{id}$ in $H_n(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n\setminus0)$, and if $E$ is the matrix representing the addition of a nonzero multiple of a row to another row, then the associated map induces $+\text{id}$ in $H_n(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n\setminus0)$. This can be achieved by observing that an elementary matrix of the former type is similar to the diagonal matrix $\operatorname{diag}(-1,1,1,\ldots, 1)$, and an elementary matrix of the latter type is similar to the identity matrix.